# Copying TFS History of two similar projects

Tags: foundation

I have two copies of the same project, say Project1 and Project2. The contents of the two projects are same. However, Project1 is having a history, and as Project2 is just a copy of Project1, it doesn't have a history of its own.

Now, to maintain a proper folder structure, I need to delete Project1 (with history) and continue the development with Project2 (without history). How can I copy the history into Project2? Since it is exact copy of Project1, I suspect there should be a way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you created "project2" by copying the source locally (on your local file system) and then adding it as a new folder to TFS.

From TFS's point of view this is a completelty new artifact to be managed. If you want "Project2" to be a continuation of the history of "project1" then you need to branch the code from "project1" to "project2".

To do this, delete "project2" from TFS, then right click on the folder containing "project1" in Source Control Explorer. Select "Branching and Merging" > "Branch" and select an appropriate destination for "project2" to be created. Then hit OK.

You should now see that "project2" has a full history up to the moment you created the branch. you can now delete "project1" if you need to.